# How to convert data in Excel to percentages of total?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-table

Is there a quick way to convert all cell values in a table to a percentage of a total listed in a separate column? I tried posting an image of my data as an example, but my reputation here isn't strong enough!

Comment: It won't let me add the picture as I need a '10 reputation!

Comment: Try adding it now! :)

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a job for [pivot table](https://support.office.com/client/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)!

Select the range and go to ***Insert - Pivot Table***

For *row labels*, have whatever your rows are.

In the *values field* place your numbers, click the drop down and go to **value field settings**.

Now *show value as* and select **% of total** in the drop-down.

Now they are summarized by percentage of total!

[click for full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSxvJ.png)
[image]